# Vue scroll элемента при обновлении данных

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Доброго времени суток.

На сайте есть блок чата с сообщениями. Метод загрузки сообщений:

```
getMessages () {
                if(this.currentPage <= this.lastPage) {
                    this.getChatMessages({ userId: this.activeChatUser.id, page: this.currentPage })
                        .then(result => {
                            this.lastPage = result.messages.last_page
                            this.messages = [...result.messages.data.reverse(), ...this.messages]
                            console.log(result)
                            this.currentPage++;
                        });
                }

            },
```

Блок чата имеет определённую высоту и соответственно скролл. При загрузке первой страницы сообщений блок должен проскролится вниз (для примера указано значение 100):

```
updated() {
            if(this.currentPage === 1 && typeof this.$refs.messageArea !== 'undefined'){
              
                this.$refs.messageArea.scrollBy(0, 100);
                
                // 0
                console.log(this.$refs.messageArea.scrollTop);
            }
        },
```

Но скролла не происходит, scrollTop равен 0. В чём может быть проблема?

PS. С документации Vue, хук updated - данные обновлены, обновлено DOM-дерево. Через консооль инструментов разработчика всё работает.

Comment: А если подебажить?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ кроется в **цикле событий** *(Event Loop)* самого JavaScript.

Хук update будет вызван только после полной отработки метода.

Поскольку в методе инкрементировалось значение текущей странички (по дефолту было 1):

```
// стало 2
this.currentPage++;
```

условие не выполнялось:

```
if(this.currentPage === 1 && typeof this.$refs.messageArea !== 'undefined')
```